# Conditions for distinct eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,

1. Under what conditions (e.g. symmetric, positive definite, etc.) will it have $n$ distinct eigenvalues?
2. Under what conditions will it have $n$ distinct linearly independent eigenvectors? (eigenvalues corresponding to these eigenvectors need not be distinct)
3. Is $\text{rank}(A) = n$ always equivalent to having $n$ distinct eigenvalues or eigenvectors?

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 are strange questions to ask that have no nice direct answers. At least, there are no "nice" equivalent versions that make checking whether these hold any easier than just computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix. If there is a particular use for answers to these questions that you have in mind, it would be helpful if you would [edit] your question to add that context in.

Comment: The answer to 3 is simply no. $A$ can be full rank without $n$ distinct eigenvalues (or eigenvectors), and it can also have rank less than $n$ with $n$ distinct eigenvalues (and eigenvectors).

Comment: Also, note that the phrase "$n$ distinct eigenvectors" is not correct (or at least, probably not what you mean). For example, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
has the 2 **distinct** eigenvectors $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$, but it is not diagonalizable because it does not have a set of $n = 2$ **linearly independent** eigenvectors.

Comment: @BenGrossmann For 1 and 2, I was looking for the smallest set of "constraints" on $A$ that lead to those properties. Yes, I meant distinct linearly independent eigenvectors -- will edit.

Comment: Again, if you're literally looking for **the smallest** set of constraints on $A$ that lead to these properties, then you're looking for a condition that's equivalent to these properties, and there's no such condition that's makes checking any easier than just computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in some fashion

Comment: There are no general conditions for 1. If you assume some structure for the matrix, for instance, if the matrix is triangular with distinct elements on the diagonal. As Ben Grossmann said, there are no conditions that are easier than just checking the eigenvalues in the general case.

Comment: @helper In other words, it is very likely that you are asking the wrong questions. It would be helpful if you could tell us **why** you are asking these questions so that we could steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @BenGrossmann $(1)$ could be characterized as the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits into $n$ linear factors, while $(2)$ could be characterized as the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors. Verifying these claims can in some cases be easier than computing all eigenvalues.

Comment: @mechanodroid In some cases, sure. You're welcome to write an answer to that effect. Maybe the asker will be satisfied with that. What is far more likely in my experience, however, is that the asker will say "I don't know what a minimal polynomial is" or "is there some way to compute the minimal polynomial that's faster than getting eigenvalues?" and, if you want to provide a satisfactory answer, you'll have to continue playing a guessing game until you find an answer that happens to be suited to the asker's background and context.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I completely agree, this is exactly why I decided to just write a comment and leave the answering to someone more willing (or wait for the asker to provide more context).

Comment: @BenGrossmann there is no specific **why**, I was just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A matrix has distinct eigenvalues iff the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) is nonzero. This is pretty tedious to compute away from the $2 \times 2$ or possibly the $3 \times 3$ case, though. But it can sometimes be theoretically useful to know that "almost all" matrices have this property (more precisely, that the set of matrices which do not have this property has measure zero).
2. A matrix has a basis of eigenvectors iff it's [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) (this is more or less just a restatement of definitions). By the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), a sufficient but not necessary condition for this to be true is that the matrix is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). A different sufficient but not necessary condition is that the eigenvalues are distinct.
3. No, this is neither necessary nor sufficient. A zero matrix is diagonalizable but has rank zero, a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) with nonzero eigenvalue is full rank but not diagonalizable, the matrix $\text{diag}(0, 1)$ has distinct eigenvalues but does not have full rank, and again a Jordan block with nonzero eigenvalue has full rank but does not have distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer. Do you have a proof or a reference for this claim: "almost all" matrices have this property (more precisely, that the set of matrices which do not have this property has measure zero).